# Convert excel sheet to .txt, and numbers should copy without inverted commas "" in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save an excel sheet to .txt format so that it can be used in SAP.
The problem I have is that there is a column which contains numbers and when I then convert the Excel sheet to .txt format, the numbers appear with inverted commas "", e.g. 33837 changes to "33837".

It is important to me that the number does not appear with inverted commas because SAP does not recognize this and gives an error.

Additionally, because the user is in Europe, the decimal separator should be a comma (,) while the thousand separator should be a full-stop (.) I was able to set the number formatting with the following code:

```
For i = 4 To lRow
    If (currentS.Cells(i, 30) = "") Then
    Else

 Dim S As String
 Dim D As Double
 Const myDecSep As String = ","
 Const myThousSep As String = "."

D = currentS.Cells(i, 30).Value
S = Format(D, "#,##0.00")

S = Replace(S, Application.DecimalSeparator, Chr(1))
S = Replace(S, Application.ThousandsSeparator, Chr(2))
S = Replace(S, Chr(1), myDecSep)
S = Replace(S, Chr(2), myThousSep)
    newS.Cells(i - 2, 28).Value = S
    End If
Next
```

After I copy all cells I need to a new Excel sheet(newS) in a new Excel workbook (newWB). I then save this new workbook to .txt format with the below code:

```
newWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\oyin\Desktop\Service.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

The below pic is the .txt file which is saved. I need the number to appear as 33.837,00 instead of "33.837,00"
[.txt picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOa5b.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please, change:

```
newWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\oyin\Desktop\Service.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

with:

```
newWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\oyin\Desktop\Service.txt", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
```

**Edited:**

Please, try the next way:

```
newWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\oyin\Desktop\Service.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False, local:=False
```

Comment: @Oyin: Did you find some time to check the above suggestion? Didn't it work in order to solve your problem?

Comment: The inverted commas were removed, but it created more problems. It now appears as 33.837,0EUR. I want 2 decimal places. Secondly, the EUR should be in a separate column like in the picture I attached to the question.

Comment: @Oyin Do you see what you show me in the text file, **opening it with Notepad**, or when you try opening it in Excel?

Comment: @Oyin Please, try the last suggestion. I edited the answer and place another code line. I think/suppose that your problem is related to your localization...

Comment: Thank you for your help but it still doesn't work. I still get "33.837,00" when I open the .txt as a Notepad. I always open with Notepad. It is properly formatted in Excel. The issue arises when I save the Excel file as .txt file.